# How to stop pointer from blinking while time updates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that contains a time stamp that updates every single second. While this happens, the pointer constantly blinks. Is it possible to disable the blinking effect of the pointer *without disabling automatic calculation and screen updating (for the time)*?

Answer (score 1):

insert the following at the start of your code:-

```
Application.Cursor = xlwait
```

insert this line at the end of your code:-

```
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
```